# How do I fix ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED error when making an npm command in gitbash

Tags: node.js, npm, openssl, create-react-app, git-bash

Every time I run npm create-react-app my-app or any npm command in gitbash console I get this error:
`npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED npm ERR! BC0D0000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:npm ERR!`

I tried many solutions I found in the web, from reinstalling node js, installing the new openssl version, reinstalling git bash (console), allowed gitbash and nodejs through firewall, used AI chatbots but gave me vague useless answers, running this command `npm config set strict-ssl false` and even formatted the whole PC.
I already asked this question 2 months ago but did not receive any solutions if anyone have any clue how to solve it please respond to me. I had paused learning react/electron because of this issue.

Comment: may i ask, how did you solve this? i am also encountering this. my npm and node are all up to date and tried also what you have done their on your post. aw. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above as well with no success. (no-ssl, config proxy reset, cache reset)

I resetted my WI-FI network on Windows, reconnected and it worked.

So you have to reset network settings in windows at least in my case or try with a different network in order to avoid this SSL Cipher error.

Comment: I resetted the network settings and still get the issue, changed from office wifi to mobile hotspot still same issue, I believe it must have to do with the network adapter, unfortunately that's the only one I have at the moment. When I buy a new one ill see if it resolves it or not.